# .htaccess doens't work on subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I wrote a little .htaccess document, to rewrite url's from 127.0.0.1/index.php?page=dashboard to 127.0.0.1/dashboard. This works fine on my localhost, but when I place it on the subdomain of a domain name, it stops working.
Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ login.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^logout/?$ logout.php [NC]
```

Comment: It looks like htaccess is ignored. Check if override is allowed in document root in your apache configuration.

Comment: Check if mod_rewrite is enabled on the server

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled, and htaccess is not ignored, as DirectoryIndex works fine.

Comment: This `.htaccess` file's contents do not match what you describe in your question.

Comment: It does, I just didn't display the directory index line.

Comment: I don't see any rules that match against `dashboard`

Comment: It's just a part of the htaccess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed the problem. It seemed that the host was running on Linu, and thus case sensitive. My Apache server wasn't, so that was the problem. Thanks for all the help tough!